# How can you get 100% unit test coverage on a Multiplatform Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

This is the most I seem to be able to extract this property.  However, I'd like to run one test for a different ios simulator.  Is there a way to do this?

```swift
var isNavigationStackAvailable: Bool { 
  if #available(iOS 16.0, macOS 13.0, *) {
    return true
  } else { 
    return false
  } 
}
```

Comment: I found a “good enough” answer, to create multiple schemes, with each ones destination on a different simulator, then create a script so that xcode build runs all the schemes for tests, then aggregates that for code coverage.

Comment: Hi. That code does not look like Scheme language and the tag `scheme` is just for that language and not for eg. url scheme or whatever this is about.

Comment: @Sylwester The comment is fine, but you have the power to edit the tags yourself as well. No need to leave this question floating around in an inaccurate tag.